# Should I flush the response in a Filter before doing post processing to improve latency?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am running a Tomcat web server and have a a filter chain configured to sit in front of my servlets. All the filters in the chain do post processing of the request like logging etc and do not modify the contents of the response.

What I noticed is that the response is not returned to the client until all the filters have finished processing the response and this increases the latency of the response. I fixed this by adding a Filter in the bottom of the chain that does the following

```
response.flushBuffer()
```

This ensures that the response flushed to the kernel before the other filters do their post processing. **My question is whether this is a standard practice or if there are better ways to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

The valid and logical action would be optimize the code and the business, and if it's heavy naturally, so you need more process power.

It depends on what filters after the chain do?

If they affect the response meta/header, so flushing might not help since the header must go first.

Sharing the filters, and the servlet codez would help to find the best solution.